# How to fix HockeyApp namespace error in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, hockeyapp

I built an old hockey App project using Xamarin.
But I got some errors.

> CS0234    The type or namespace name 'CrashManagerListener' does not
> exist in the namespace 'HockeyApp' (are you missing an assembly
> reference?)
>
> CS0234    The type or namespace name 'TraceWriter' does not
> exist in the namespace 'HockeyApp' (are you missing an assembly
> reference?)

I installed HockeySDK.Xamarin using Nugat package manager of VS2015.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the added NuGet Package to your project?

Comment: I added HockeySDK and HockeySDK.AndroidBindings

Comment: Did that resolve your issue - or are you still receiving the error?

Comment: I didn't fix yet.
As I say again, I added the above two things but got some errors I mentioned.

Comment: Have you added the proper `using` statements to match for each added reference?  The errors you are receiving are because of either 1. Missing reference to the NuGet Package(s) 2. Lacking proper using statement 3. Depending on how old the project is that you are trying to build you may have selected the wrong version of NuGet package, and the `CrashManagerListner` and `TraceWriter` no longer exist in the version you installed.

Comment: If you updated to the latest HockeySDK, you should be able to use HockeyApp.Android namespace